# VBA Matrix search

Tags: vba, search, matrix

Im having issues with adding values to a Matrix. The first part is working fine, where i am adding values to columns 1-7 from "Example".

However, i have another sheet from which i want to lookup values for Matrix's column 8. The value I want can be found if i can lookup the Example(i,3), which is stored in the Matrix. How do I search a another range for the value that is stored in the Matrix?

Currently im getting the object not defined error on row: "Set cl = ExampleSet2(i, 10).Find(Example(i, 3), LookIn:=xlValues)"

```
ReDim Matrix(1 To x, 1 To 8)
x = 0

For i = LBound(Example) To UBound(Example)

    If CStr(Example(i, DDKolumn)) = DDKey Then
    x = x + 1
    Matrix(x, 1) = Example(i, 8) & "  |  " & Example(i, 2)
    Matrix(x, 2) = Example(i, 1)
    Matrix(x, 3) = Example(i, 3)
    Matrix(x, 4) = Example(i, 4)
    Matrix(x, 5) = Example(i, 5)
    Matrix(x, 6) = Example(i, 6)
    Matrix(x, 7) = Example(i, 7)

        For y = LBound(ExampleSet2) To UBound(ExampleSet2)
            With Sheet14
            Set cl = ExampleSet2(i, 10).Find(Example(i, 3), LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not cl Is Nothing Then
            Matrix(x, 8) = ExampleSet2(y, 11)
            End If
            End With
        Next y

    End If

Next i
```

Comment: Really suggest you use different names for your variables. `Range` and `Range2` are easily confused with the built-in `Range` object. Which btw explains your problem - `Range.Find` is a method of a `Range` object... which is not what you have here.

Comment: ExampleSet2 is another sheet, defined as:
   `Variable= Sheets("Example").Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Row
    Range2 = Sheets("Example").Range("A20:I" & Variable)`

Ahh sorry i had to change the names i am referring to due to privacy. So basically Range, Range2 and Matrix are not the "names" i am using. The names are actually, ill change them to the code to avoid confusion.

Comment: Okay the entire thing should be now be updated so that "confusing" names are no-longer in the set.. Sorry about that, didnt realize it when making "fake names"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Find` is a method of a `Range` object. `ExampleSet` is a `Variant` array, not a `Range`.

```
ExampleSet2 = Sheets("Example").Range("A20:I" & Variable) '<~ this is not a Range object
```

I honestly don't see why you need an array, or even a loop. Just use a `Range`, and make sure to `Set`.

```
Dim ExampleSet2 as Range
Set ExampleSet2 = Sheets("Example").Range("A20:I" & Variable)
```

Now you can `.Find` on `ExampleSet2` or on a subset of it.

Comment: I changed it to a range, but now the `For y = LBound(ExampleSet2) To UBound(ExampleSet2)` expects an array, not a range.

Comment: But my point is that you probably don't need to loop. And you don't need an array.

Comment: In other words, "How do I search a another range for the value that is stored in the Matrix" - can you explain *why* you need a loop to do this? You don't need a loop if you are `Find`ing.

Comment: Ahh i think i got what you mean, but im not sure how to excecute it. So basically just making another line:

 `Matrix(x, 8) = ExampleSet2.Find(Example(i, 3), LookIn:=xlValues)` 

Now it currently says that an object is required. I have ExampleSet2 currently defined as a Variant

Comment: Please - reread my answer. `Dim ExampleSet2 As Range`, and then `Set` it. You can only use `Find` on a `Range` object.

Comment: Ahh thank you! And sorry its not that i didn't read, but i think it might be difficult for you to understand how little I understand of the somewhat "simple" things, no matter how clearly you point it out  :)